# PHP: How to check if a <p> has a child node of <iframe> with DOMDocument?

Tags: php, iframe, domdocument

How can I check if a `p` has a child node of `iframe` with `DOMDocument`?

For instance,

```
<p><iframe ....></p>
```

I want to print this only,

```
<iframe ....>
```

While,

```
<p>bla bla bal</p>
```

then do nothing or just print whatever inside the p,

```
<p>bla bla bal</p>
```

Or,

```
<p>bla bla <b>bal</b></p>
```

then do nothing or just print whatever inside the p,

```
<p>bla bla <b>bal</b></p>
```

my php,

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($item_html);

if($dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->length > 1 )
{
    ...
}
else // if it is only a single paragraph... then do what I want above...
{

    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $node)
    {
        if ($node->hasChildNodes()) 
        {
           foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe') as $iframe ) 
            {
               ... something
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ... 
        }
     }
}
```

is it possible?

Comment: My guess is that you can. Have you proved?

Comment: `if ($node->hasChildNodes()) ` does not specifically for `iframe` - it detect any kind of node inside `p`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to find all iframe elements that are the only childnodes of the p elements.

If found you want to replace their parent p element with them.

```
/** @var DOMElement $p */
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('p') as $p) {
    if ($p->childNodes->length !== 1) {
        continue;
    }

    $child = $p->childNodes->item(0);

    if (! $child instanceof DOMElement) {
        continue;
    }

    if ($child->tagName !== 'iframe') {
        continue;
    }

    $p->parentNode->insertBefore($child, $p);
    $p->parentNode->removeChild($p);
}
```

This foreach loop just iterates over all p elements, ignores all that don't have a single child node that is not a DOMElement with the iframe tagname (note: always lowercase in the compare).

If one p element is found, then the inner iframe is moved before it and then the paragraph is removed.

Usage Example:

```
<?php
/**
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/q/19021983/367456
 */

$html = '
<p><iframe src="...."></p>
<p>bla bla bal</p>
<p>bla bla <b>bal</b></p>
<p></p>
';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

/** @var DOMElement[] $ps */
// $ps = $;

/** @var DOMElement $p */
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('p') as $p) {
    if ($p->childNodes->length !== 1) {
        continue;
    }

    $child = $p->childNodes->item(0);

    if (!$child instanceof DOMElement) {
        continue;
    }

    if ($child->tagName !== 'iframe') {
        continue;
    }

    $p->parentNode->insertBefore($child, $p);
    $p->parentNode->removeChild($p);
}

// output
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $child) {
    echo $doc->saveHTML($child);
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/51220) and Output:

```
<iframe src="...."></iframe>
<p>bla bla bal</p>
<p>bla bla <b>bal</b></p>
<p></p>
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

So do this:

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($item_html);

    if($dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->length > 1 )
    {
        ...
    }
    else // if it is only a single paragraph... then do what I want above...
    {

        foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $node)
        {
            if ($node->hasChildNodes()) 
            {
                if($dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe')->length > 0 )
                  {
                  foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe') as $iframe ) 
                   {
                      ... something
                   }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ... 
            }
         }
    }
```